# PHP: figure out is php expression complete?

Tags: php, parsing, static-analysis, php-parser

I'm trying to port Slim templating language (http://www.slim-lang.com) to PHP. There are a couple of niceties that I would like to make available for PHP too, but I can't w/o figuring out is expression complete or not.

For example this code:

```
- 1.upto(10)
    = i
```

will be actually interpreted as

```
1.upto(10) {
    print i
}
```

Slim will add {} itself. For this parsing of expression is required. What I need to determine is should I put brace and if yes then where?

My version of Slim implementation will translate slim files to PHP templates, so result from this code:

```
- for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) /// a comment
    = $i
```

should be

```
<? for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) { /// a comment ?>
    <?= $i ?>
<? } ?>
```

note where { is.

I know there's `token_get_all` function, but its a lexer, I'll have to actually do whole parser by myself and I would like to avoid reimplementation of parser (too much for such small thing).

So is this solveable? Non-PHP solutions are ok too.